# AngularJS - How do you get full model name all the way back to the $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I want to get the name of a model going all the way back to the `$rootScope`. So, something that looks like: `$rootScope.ctrlScope.foobar.modelName`.

I want it to be able to update that model from anywhere and to take into consideration variable model names like: `box[$index].value`. Where `$index` becomes `0`.

The reason I want this is because I'm creating a directive that gets this new model name and it's value and sends it up via a socket to NodeJS where it comes back down to another user and updates the same model on their end.

The way I tried doing this before was getting all of the use cases and designing special callbacks for each one. This was super buggy and obviously not very scalable. But tying each data / template change to a specific model and simply sending up that model change seems like a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I think the solution you are going for is likely to be just as buggy and just as un-scalable...

Comment: @tennisgent could you expand on that thought?

Comment: The idea behind modules is that they are autonomous and not coupled to any other modules, and therefore are testable.  If you write code that requires that the `$rootScope` have attributes related to other controllers, you are going to quickly have a coupled, nested, interdependent mess... The controller you're writing is now dependent upon all of the other controllers in your app

Comment: I think you are mistaken with regard to this particular case. There is only the single `rootScope` in an application. I'm bypassing controllers and dependencies entirely. That's the whole purpose of using `rootScope` here.